# SnakeYaml preserve bean property name case

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

In snakeyaml I need to preserver the bean property name.

I have following bean.

```
    public class MyBean{

        private String Name;
        private String Param;

        //getter and setter methods.
    }
```

Now when I dump this bean using following.

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.setName("Foo");
    myBean.setParam("Bar");

    DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
    options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);

    Representer representer = new Representer();
    representer.addClassTag(MyBean.class, Tag.MAP);

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer, options);

    String output = yaml.dump(myBean);
    System.out.println(output);

}
}
```

Output:

```
name: Foo
param: Bar
```

But I want something like :

```
Name: Foo
Param: Bar
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without specifying a [custom representer](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers), but I may be wrong.

Comment: @flyx I can't found any Representer to do so.

Comment: You have to implement one. But if you do, afaik you cannot load the YAML again without adding an explicit tag to your mapping because there is no other way to invoke a custom constructor that can load the YAML according to your needs again.